# Dynamic increasing counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter, long-polling

I was wondering what would be the "best" way of making an counter in javascript or jQuery that would respond to data from a database? The purpose is that it should show the amount of people currently taking part of surveys in different countries. I guess I would need to hook it to sán Ajax request and maybe do some kind of long polling solution that "listens" for updates in the database. Any good pointers to this?

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BEST way would be using comet, which allows to have "server events" that are pushed to the client (as facebook and many other sites do), but it's relatively hard to implement.

[The cometd project](http://cometd.org/)

One easy way, would be using setInterval.

```
setInterval(function(){
   $.ajax({
     ...
   });
}, 5000);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to update this value dynamically or is it sufficient to get the value on page load?

If it is necessary, then yes, make an ajax request to fetch the number.

EDIT:

And make the request on regular intervals, using for instance `setInterval`.

Comment: I think that it would be sufficient if it would do it on regular intervals, setInterval is a good idea.